# Refresh browser without "Confirm Form Resubmission" in perl

Tags: html, perl, google-chrome, browser

I have a perl script that prints out HTML code and runs actions based on user input in the HTML page. I would like to be able to disable the "Confirm Form Resubmission" warning and prevent the users from repeating the last command ran. I saw some posts that solve this issue in php, but not sure how I would do it with perl.

Thanks!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The usual technique for preventing this is the [Post/Get Redirect pattern](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Post/Redirect/Get).

This doesn't stop browsers from behaving as they do, but it redirects users to a new page after a successful POST, so that if they refresh they are not repeating the POST, but repeating the GET instead, which doesn't cause a warning.

Here is an example of the flow:

- GET "Products/Create"
- User types in some information
- POST "Products/Create"
- Validation fails, re-display the form with warnings - user corrects the input
- POST "Products/Create"
- Validation passes, item is saved redirect, using a GET to "Products/View/5"
- User refreshes the page, this results in a harmless GET "Products/View/5"

To issue a redirect, you can use:

```
use CGI;
my $query=new CGI;
print $query->redirect('http://www.example.com/newpage');
```

Comment: I'm sorry, maybe I'm not understanding, when i input that code, I'm getting stuff actually printed out like "Status: 302 Moved Location: test.pl" on my page instead of an actual redirect. If i put that code before i do print "Content-type: text/html\n\n"; then it puts me in an infinite redirect loop

Comment: You must only run the code when the POST is successful, not at any other time. Redirections must be placed before any content is written (as you have discovered).

Comment: That makes complete sense now, i don't know how i didn't get that at first. thanks!